# Travar rotação ao clicar

Tags: android, unity3d, rotação, mouse

Estou fazendo um Puzzle mas travei em uma parte. Me parece simples, mas não consigo achar uma solução. Bom, estou usando o mouse para clicar em um objeto para que ele rotacione até um certo ângulo, mas eu queria que ao clicar no mesmo objeto mais uma vez, o clique fosse bloqueado, sendo assim, a pessoa que estiver jogando, continue rotacionando os outros objetos sem conseguir girar o que ja foi clicado.
Quero que clique, pare, siga para o próximo quadradinho clicando e por ai vai, pq após clicar em todos, a fase acaba, aparace YOUWIN.

Estou usando esse Script para rotação

private void OnMouseDown()
{
if (!GameControl.youWin)
transform.Rotate(0f,0f,90f);
}
}

ME AJUDEM KK OBRIGADA!!

Answer (score 0):

A sua pergunta não ficou muito clara, mas se eu entendi direito, você quer permitir só um clique por objeto, certo?

Minha sugestão é criar uma variável `bool clicked` no script do seu objeto, que vai guardar se já foi clicado ou não. E usar ela pra decidir o que fazer quando você detecta um clique:

```
public class RotatingObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool clicked = false;
      
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        // Se ainda não foi clicado
        if (!clicked)
        {
            // Roda o código que gira o objeto
            // ...

            // Marca como clicado pra impedir de girar denovo
            clicked = true;
        }
    }
}
```